# Python - import error in matplotlib raindrop example

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to run [Nicolas Rougier's raindrop animation](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/rain.html) using `matplotlib` (version 1.4.3) on my Python 2.7.10 IDLE (running on a Mac, OS X 10.10.5) but am getting the following import error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
....
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 34, in <module>
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure, figaspect
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 40, in <module>
    from matplotlib.axes import Axes, SubplotBase, subplot_class_factory
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ._subplots import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_subplots.py", line 10, in <module>
    from matplotlib.axes._axes import Axes
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 21, in <module>
    import matplotlib.dates as _  # <-registers a date unit converter
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 126, in <module>
    from dateutil.rrule import (rrule, MO, TU, WE, TH, FR, SA, SU, YEARLY,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/dateutil/rrule.py", line 16, in <module>
    from six.moves import _thread
ImportError: cannot import name _thread
```

The script I'm using is exactly the same as in the link but I had to insert the statements `import matplotlib` and `matplotlib.use('TKAgg')` before `pyplot` and `FuncAnimation` import statements at the top.

Comment: This sounds like a version incompatibility of the `six` module. (Yes, that's as ironic as it sounds, given that the `six` module is a Python 2 and 3 compatibility library created to ease the `2to3` transition). You may need to either up- or downgrade your version of `six`.

Comment: I have version 1.9.0, would you recommend an upgrade?

Comment: I really couldn't say. Unfortunately it's non-trivial to figure out what imports are available in what versions of `six`. You may get around that with just picking a different version of `dateutil`, the package that depends on `six`, like @DimitrisJim suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re-install the dateutil package for python.

```
sudo pip uninstall dateutil
sudo pip install python-dateutil==2.2
```

Comment: dateutil wasn't installed at all on my setup